# Alert message doesn't work in IE6-7-8 but in IE9 , Mozilla it works good

Tags: javascript

every body,
i need your help please.
I'm working on a javascript code and i try to test it in my IE6 , IE7 , IE8 browsers but it doesn't works but in mozilla or IE9 it's good why?!

this my code.

```
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myfun()">try it</button>

<script>
function myfun(){
alert("hello,it's me!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i test also by making in the onclick button : "alert("ok");" , also this : javascript:alert();

thanx a lot

Comment: likely its doing some form of a submit.

Comment: Do you get any notification in IE? Normally script won't run if you open a file locally, without specifically allowing it.

Comment: Why would you still support IE7 or even IE6?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons in IE and other browsers cause the page to reload.  You need to return false in your function.

```
function myfun(){
  alert("hello,it's me!");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i agree with you because without return false , the page will reload but i have tested this but it didn't work and when i tested it with my own IETESTER it works su the problem com's from th IETester of the work

thxxxx